# Accidentally ran wget -O-, and it outputted stdout to terminal

Tags: wget, stdout

Accidentally ran `wget -O- https://dev.mysql.com/get/Downloads/MySQL-8.0/mysql-boost-8.0.22.tar.gz` with the `-O-` thing, and it outputted random stuff to terminal. Is it possible that it could've done damage to the system? This is a production server. pls help.

Comment: No. You have sent some output to the terminal. At worst, your terminal settings are now messed up; simply log out and back in to reset these (or try the `stty sane` command). No files have been changed.

Comment: Not on your system, no. If in doubt, run something like `find . -mmin 10` to find files that have been modified in the last 10 minutes (see `man find` ) , but I don't see how this command could have changed anything.

Comment: @Jos Is it `find . -mmin 10` or `find . -mmin -10`?

Comment: @FedonKadifeli Good point. `-10` will find files modified 10 minutes or less ago, which was what I meant.